# Error installing Ruby via RVM on Cygwin

Tags: ruby, cygwin, rvm

I'm on Cygwin and I tried to install Ruby with RVM with this command: `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`.

It seems to install RVM OK, but it throws make errors when compiling ruby-2.2.1.

```
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
ruby-2.2.1 - #removing src/ruby-2.2.1..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: cygwin/unknown/x86_64/ruby-2.2.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for cygwin.
Requirements installation successful.
Found user configured '-j' flag in 'rvm_make_flags', please note that RVM can detect number of CPU threads and set the '-j' flag automatically if you do not set it.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.1 - #downloading ruby-2.2.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.2.1 - #extracting ruby-2.2.1 to /home/xxx/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.1....
ruby-2.2.1 - #applying patch /home/xxx/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.1/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
ruby-2.2.1 - #configuring...........................................................
ruby-2.2.1 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.2.1 - #compiling.................................................
Error running '__rvm_make -j2',
showing last 15 lines of /home/xxx/.rvm/log/1449160601_ruby-2.2.1/make.log
        ^
Makefile:241: recipe for target 'printf.o' failed
make[2]: *** [printf.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/xxx/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.1/ext/-test-/printf'
exts.mk:118: recipe for target 'ext/-test-/printf/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ext/-test-/printf/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compiling receiver.c
compiling super.c
linking shared-object -test-/proc.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/xxx/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.1/ext/-test-/proc'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xxx/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.1'
uncommon.mk:189: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ /scripts/functions/support : __rvm_make()  383 > return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Full output of command is [here](https://gist.github.com/pcantalupo/e4caeb5b8af9e253f650). Is this a bug that should be submitted? What do I try next? My real purpose for wanting to do this is to eventually install Jekyll on cygwin.

Comment: Do you have to use RVM?

Comment: based on this http://matt.scharley.me/2012/03/10/windows-cygwin-and-jekyll.html I assumed that I had to.

Comment: Depending on your usage, I'd recommend using Ruby Installer for best Windows compatibility. http://rubyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently issue is resolved with Ruby 2.2.3 (https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3358). So when I executed `rvm install 2.2.3`, ruby installed just fine.